# Retrieve wallet address after connecting Metamask with Web3.js

Tags: javascript, html, web3js

I got this code off github which allows you to connect to MetaMask using web3.js and also to make payment. I then modified it to

1. Display a Connect Button when user is not logged in by checking if the content of an element is empty and if it is not empty, the connect button is hidden.
2. Retrieve the connected wallet address which is in the element that hides the button.

The problem i am facing currently is that

1. The connected wallet address does not display nor is the connect button hidden until i reload the page manually.
2. I have tried calling location.reload(); after await ethereum.enable(); which works but in turns hide the #status dialogs from displaying when a user declines making payment as a result of the page reloading instead of displaying the dialogs.

Below is my code

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/@metamask/legacy-web3@latest/dist/metamask.web3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        
      <div id="selected-account"></div>
      <button class="pay-button">Pay</button>
      <div id="status"></div>
      <div id="accTabs"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function initWeb3() {
        if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        
        try {
            
          await ethereum.enable();
    window.location.reload();
          } catch (err) {
            $("#status").html("User denied account access", err);
          }
        } else if (window.web3) {
            
          return (window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider));
          
        } else {
          return $("#status").html("No Metamask (or other Web3 Provider) installed");
        }
      }
      
      selectedAccount = ethereum.selectedAddress;
  document.querySelector("#selected-account").textContent = selectedAccount;

      $(".pay-button").click(async () => {
        await initWeb3();
        // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
        const paymentAddress = "0x192c96bfee59158441f26101b2db1af3b07feb40";
        const amountEth = "1";



        web3.eth.sendTransaction(
          {
            to: paymentAddress, 
          value: web3.toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
          },
          (err, transactionId) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Payment failed", err);
              $("#status").html("Payment failed");
            } else {
              console.log("Payment successful", transactionId);
              $("#status").html("Payment successful");
            }
          }
        );
      });
    </script>
    
    <script>
  if ($('#selected-account').text() == '') {
document.getElementById("accTabs").innerHTML = '<button onclick="initWeb3()">Connect Ethereum</button>';
} else {


}
     
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me quickly state that there may be some not well written codes here as a result of my not being very good with Javascript. Still learning.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to answer would be for you to watch this:
[YouTube video explaining exactly that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsszzOLXNzU)